# How to use request.getparameter and response.redirect in jsp file to return username and password to JAVA CLASS

Tags: java, class, jsp, authentication

I am absolutely new to java.I have JSP login page.Now I want to authenticate       username and password(hard coded) in JAVA CLASS not servelet or etc . How to do this    through jsp
     My code:

```
package FileIO;

public class Login_Authentication {

 String username;
 String password;


public String execute()
{
if(this.username.equals("buyer")
        && this.password.equals("buyPW"))
{
    return "1";

   }else
{
    return "-1";
   }            
  }

 public String getUsername()
 { return username;

   }
public void setUsername(String username)
{
this.username = username;
  }

public String getPassword()
{ return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password)
  {this.password = password;
}



}
```

Comment: why not try [**scriptlets**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html)? although they are not advisable.

Comment: I think you should post your JSP code as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can add follow code in jsp page everywhere(import you package first)
{
<%
Login_Authentication auth = new Login_Authentication();
int result = auth.execute();
out.println(result == 1 ? "you login success" : "login fail!");
%>
}
```